# Error Connecting to Oracle Database from Pentaho Report Designer

Tags: oracle, pentaho, report-designer

I am new to Pentaho, and I am struggling to set up a new database connection. I am trying to connect to an Oracle 10g database, but whenever I test the connection, I get the below error. It doesn't really seem to list any specific error message so I'm not really sure what to do or where to go from this point.

I placed ojdbc jar's in my tomcat lib folder, but maybe there is another place those should go.

Any help/hints would be greatly appreciated.

```
Error connecting to database [OFF SSP Cert] : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
Error occured while trying to connect to the database

Error connecting to database: (using class oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver)
oracle/dms/instrument/ExecutionContextForJDBC


org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
Error occured while trying to connect to the database

Error connecting to database: (using class oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver)
oracle/dms/instrument/ExecutionContextForJDBC

org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.normalConnect(Database.java:366)
org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:315)
org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:277)
org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.connect(Database.java:267)
org.pentaho.di.core.database.DatabaseFactory.getConnectionTestReport(DatabaseFactory.java:76)
org.pentaho.di.core.database.DatabaseMeta.testConnection(DatabaseMeta.java:2443)
org.pentaho.ui.database.event.DataHandler.testDatabaseConnection(DataHandler.java:510)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
org.pentaho.ui.xul.impl.AbstractXulDomContainer.invoke(AbstractXulDomContainer.java:329)
org.pentaho.ui.xul.swing.tags.SwingButton$OnClickRunnable.run(SwingButton.java:58)
java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
java.awt.Dialog$1.run(Unknown Source)
java.awt.Dialog$3.run(Unknown Source)
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
java.awt.Dialog.show(Unknown Source)
java.awt.Component.show(Unknown Source)
java.awt.Component.setVisible(Unknown Source)
java.awt.Window.setVisible(Unknown Source)
java.awt.Dialog.setVisible(Unknown Source)
org.pentaho.ui.xul.swing.tags.SwingDialog.show(SwingDialog.java:234)
org.pentaho.reporting.ui.datasources.jdbc.ui.XulDatabaseDialog.open(XulDatabaseDialog.java:237)
org.pentaho.reporting.ui.datasources.jdbc.ui.ConnectionPanel$EditDataSourceAction.actionPerformed(ConnectionPanel.java:162)
javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
java.awt.Dialog$1.run(Unknown Source)
java.awt.Dialog$3.run(Unknown Source)
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
java.awt.Dialog.show(Unknown Source)
java.awt.Component.show(Unknown Source)
java.awt.Component.setVisible(Unknown Source)
java.awt.Window.setVisible(Unknown Source)
java.awt.Dialog.setVisible(Unknown Source)
org.pentaho.reporting.ui.datasources.jdbc.ui.JdbcDataSourceDialog.performConfiguration(JdbcDataSourceDialog.java:661)
org.pentaho.reporting.ui.datasources.jdbc.JdbcDataSourcePlugin.performEdit(JdbcDataSourcePlugin.java:67)
org.pentaho.reporting.designer.core.actions.report.AddDataFactoryAction.actionPerformed(AddDataFactoryAction.java:79)
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems you are using some sort of native JDBC driver. Make sure that the native libararies are there and can be read at runtime. You probably have to copy more than one jar into the lib/jdbc directory to make it work.

Your Oracle manual should contain all the details on how to install a JDBC driver.